# Laravel 5.1 - URLs in masterpage links

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am begining with Laravel 5.1 and I have encounter with a problem.

In my routes (as Laravel docs suggest for auth) I have the routes `auth/login` and `auth/register`. When I am in the home page `/` everything is fine, but when I am in `/auth/login` and click the register link the url duplicates auth parameter like this `/auth/auth/register`.

**Routes**

```
// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

**Master Page Nav Menu**

```
 @if (!Auth::check())
             <li><a href="auth/login">Login </a></li>
             <li><a href="auth/register">Register</a></li>
               @else (Auth::check())
                   <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="">Dashboard</a></li>
                        <li><a href="auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
                      </ul>
                   </li>
                   </ul>
             @endif
```

What I can do for avoid the duplicate url term?

NOTE: I am running a local machine with XAMPP, my complete url is `http://localhost/myproject/public/` (I am still investigating how to make public folder dissapear). If I put the route like `/auth/login` the `myproject` and `public` folders of the url dissapear on click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always start the links with a slash so you are never given a relative path based on the current one. This should fix your problems:

```
 @if (!Auth::check())
   <li><a href="/auth/login">Login </a></li>
   <li><a href="/auth/register">Register</a></li>
 @else (Auth::check())
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">{{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="/auth/logout">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   </ul>
@endif
```

You might also want to check linking to actual routes instead of hardcoding the URLs. Since Laravel5 does not come with the HTML `illuminate/html` package anymore, you'll have to include it yourself (it's actually `laravelcollective/html` now) and can use various functions to link to your routes. There's some decent documentation [here](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html) and the part I am talking about is ["Generating URLs"](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#generating-urls).

Comment: That brings a bit of light about urls. Can I put `$url = route('routeName', $params);` in blade templates?

Comment: Sorry, I've linked to Laravel 4. If you are using [Laravel's HTML package](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html), you can just use the methods in blade, like mentioned [here](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#generating-urls).

Comment: Thanks a lot, your links gave me the solution!

Answer (score 1):

This is no problem with Laravel, but with the way you build your anchor tags.
If you don't add a `/` in front of a relative url, the browser will append the relative url to the current url.

The solution is to add an `/` this will tell the browser to append the relative url to the root url.

So, you should use

```
<li><a href="/auth/login">Login </a></li>
<li><a href="/auth/register">Register</a></li>
```

Comment: I didnt say its a Laravel problem, I know it is my fault. I edited to show you why I had put the url this way (I am working in a local machine with subfolders and this links overrides my subfolder),